# Limit server populated HTML dropdown list (w/ JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am wanting to try to change or limit a drop down list using JavaScript, or some other solution.  Unfortunately, I have no control over the way the HTML comes out that I am trying to change client side.  The drop down list is generated server side, but we would like to give the user additional options to further limit the choices in the drop down list.

We can't edit what is generated, but we can insert HTML.

One suggested solution, which may not be possible, is to use JavaScript to limit the dropdown list.  For example, the drop down follows the format of:

```
<SELECT ID="dropdown_1">
<OPTION VALUE=""    >None
<OPTION VALUE="1000">AB-ITEM 1 DESCRIPTION
<OPTION VALUE="2001">AB-ITEM 2 DESCRIPTION
<OPTION VALUE="50"  >AB-ITEM 8 DESCRIPTION
<OPTION VALUE="70"  >BB-ITEM 3 DESCRIPTION
<OPTION VALUE="100" >BB-ITEM 5 DESCRIPTION
<OPTION VALUE="2"   >ABB-ITEM 4 DESCRIPTION
</SELECT>
```

What I want to limit by the beginning of the text, so `AB-`, `BB-`, or `ABB-` in this case. The `value` has no rhyme or reason, it's just an index number.  I don't think this is possible since this is just text, and not associated with an attribute.

One thought would be to be to:

- Store the list into a JavaScript array
- Keep only entries like 'TYPE-X%'
- Delete original HTML list
- Replace with new list stored in the Array

However, I'm not sure if this is possible, and if it is, what would be needed to create such code.  Any help or references to functions or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you make a call from the client to the server to initiate the population of the select element? If so, show this code

Comment: I think it is PL/SQL and it is a big mess to try to maintain it.  Any updates require us to restore all non-base-line processes, so we stay away from them as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown_1 option").hide();
    $("#dropdown_1 option").filter(":contains(TYPE-X)").show();
});
```

An advantage with this is that all of the options are still there, you just can't see them. So all it would take to return to the default list would be a call to:

```
$("#dropdown_1 option").show();
```

Edit for regex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown_1 option").hide();
    $("#dropdown_1 option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().match(/^AB-/);
    }).show();
});
```

You can filter your list using a regex like seen above.

Edit: A note about jQuery, `this` in the filter function is the DOM element itself. In order to access the jQuery helper method `text()`, I first need to wrap that DOM element with the jQuery function, as edited above.

Comment: I didn't think it could be that simple... but it's that simple!  Thank you for the quick reply.  The only problem I can see is that instead of 'TYPE-AB-' it's really just 'AB-'.  So we might have types of 'BB-' and 'ABB-' and doing contains 'BB-' will pull both.  Is there way to denote a beginning of a string or text like in regular expression (the '^' I think).

Edit:  Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Just be careful that none of those options contain information you don't want a user accessing, or that they give the user the ability to do something unwanted. When they are hidden, they are only a right click away from clever users.

Comment: @Phillip I added a regex example to my answer. Also, kyle's point is very valid. Anything done with JS can be very easily undone.

Comment: @KyleWeller That shouldn't be a problem.  This is just to help users choose more accurate options, since the options can be confusing.  It won't hurt anything for them to see the entire list, at least not for what we are using it for.  Thanks for the information!

Comment: @BinaryTox1n When I use the regex, it hides all the options.  I pulled  the text of one of the options using `alert($("#dropdown_1 option[value='40']").text())
` and it showed 'AAB-information', so the text is there.  I tried dumbing the regex to just `match(/A/)`, but it still hid all options in the dropdown. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Phillip sorry, I made a nooby jQuery mistake. I've updated the answer. Note the updated `$(this)` in the filter function.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n No worries, I am grateful the help!  This works great EXCEPT Chrome doesn't seem to handle this well when there are only a few options (maybe 10-6 or less).  If there is only 1 or 2, you can't even see the additional options when you click the drop down arrow.  What happens is the drop down list shrinks when there are fewer options, and it's fine in Firefox (yet to test other browsers) but in Chrome, if there are too few, you can't see the drop down box, or you have to scroll 1 or 2 options at a time.  Found you can disable options, and it works okay, but not my favorite option.

Comment: @Phillip I recommend you take your updated code and post a new question, as you've graduated from this problem and are now experiencing a new difficulty. That will give you a chance to properly explain what's going on and get new people to look at your question.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n  Will do. I thought I'd mention that using `.attr('disabled', true)` is necessary along with `.hide()`.  The reason being that the user can use arrow keys to walk through the hidden information.   Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BinaryTox1n, I was put on a good path to find an all-browser compatible solution to my question.  However, it is a slightly different approach pieced together from other solutions on StackOverFlow.

The difference comes is how one deals with the `OPTION`s.  Though `.hide()` works on some browsers, it is not compatible with IE8 (and maybe some others).  Alternatives and variations to `.hide()` also failed.  Another problem with `.hide()` is that you also need to use `.disable()`.  The last problem is that if you have several (20 or so) options and only 2 or 3 are visible, Chrome (and perhaps other browsers) do not render the dropdown box properly.

The best approach found is to `.remove()` unwanted options.  No compatibility issues because the `OPTION` is simply removed.  However, I also want to have the flexibility to add back options if needed.  So the following is a version of what I'll be using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var regex_str = "^AAB-";
    var dd1 = $("#dropdown1 option");

  //Clone the 'None', Current, and All options into respective variables.
  //All options are stored in order to allow different selection criteria
    var all_Opt  = dd1.clone(true);
    var none_Opt = dd1.filter(":contains(None)").clone(true);
    var cur_Opt  = dd1.filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().match(regex_str);
    }).clone(true);

  //Remove all options and replace the 'None' and Current options
    dd1.remove();
    noneOpt.appendTo($("#dropdown1"));
    curOpt.appendTo($("#dropdown1"));
});
</script>
```

The only thing I'd like to add is the ability for this to change using a different drop down box or some other trigger.